# Getting a list of checkboxes except one

Tags: jquery

I have the following Jquery code:

```
var $others = $('input[type="checkbox"]')
```

But I want to exclude a checkbox where the Value is "All"

```
<input checked="checked" id="role_ids_" name="role_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="All" />
              <input checked="checked" id="role_ids_" name="role_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="Age" />
              <input checked="checked" id="role_ids_" name="role_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="field" />
              <input checked="checked" id="role_ids_" name="role_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="product" />
              <input checked="checked" id="role_ids_" name="role_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="officer" />
              <input checked="checked" id="role_ids_" name="role_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="regional" />
```

Can I use something like `not()`?

Comment: just add class for every element that you wanna select and $(".YOUR_SELECTOR");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Attribute Not Equal Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/):

```
var $others = $('input[type="checkbox"][value!="All"]');
```

If you already have an initialized context, and only want to filter it, you can use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
var $elms = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
var $others = $elms.not('[value="All"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
var $others = $('input[type="checkbox"]:not([value="All"])')
```

should work, where you use the `:not` pseudo-selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('input[value!="All"]')`

Also, do not assign same id to all checkboxes. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the [Attribute Not Equal Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4jo3tL54

```
var $others = $('input[type="checkbox"][value!="All"]')

$.each($others, function( i, v ) {
     console.log(v.value);
});
```